# How to check if an editText box(s) is empty or not in android using Java

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-edittext

In my app, I have around 5 editText boxes in every screen.I want to check if they are empty or not and if all the text boxes are not empty, then there is an intent which takes you to the next screen. I want to know what code to write.

Comment: Can you post what you have until now? and what you have been trying to do?

Comment: Basically I am developing an app for people to create Portfolios. It has a few editText boxes so I wanna check if they are empty or not. I am only a beginner in Android App development. So I would be needing some help.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this code in your java file when you want to call the intent.

```
EditText editTextBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editTextBox1_id);
EditText editTextBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editTextBox2_id);
EditText editTextBox3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editTextBox3_id);
EditText editTextBox4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editTextBox4_id);
EditText editTextBox5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editTextBox5_id);

if((editTextBox1.getText().length() != 0) && (editTextBox2.getText().length() != 0) && (editTextBox3.getText().length() != 0) && (editTextBox4.getText().length() != 0) && (editTextBox5.getText().length() != 0)){
    //Start Activity
}
else{
    //else show an error or anything you want
}
```

Here, just replace the `your_editTextBox1_id` with the `ID` you set in your `xml` file.

If you want to check it when a `Button` is clicked, just add this code in the `OnClick` method of the button.